# Character encoding changed when upgrading EE

Tags: character-encoding

Earlier this year, I upgraded a site from EE 1.x to EE 2.x. I have only now discovered that in the process of doing so, it seems the encoding changed on my old posts, so that Swedish letters (for example) are replaced with their respective character references.

Is it possible to fix all of those old posts in some handy fashion so that they just store those characters as-is, as newer posts do?

Comment: I had a similar issue on a Japanese site that I upgraded, and my "handy fashion" was to have EL tech support fix it..;)  If you have a support plan I'd pursue that route.

Comment: I don't currently have a support plan, but it might be worth getting one for a while to sort that out. The frontend display seems fine from what I can tell, but the backend gets messy.